# Quantum Computing Daily Practice / Quiz platform

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms

I am looking for a platform where I can solve quizzes and programming / algorithmic challenges related to quantum computation and information.

To be more specific, I am looking for a platform that is analogous to LeetCode, Codeforces, Kaggle, CodePen, etc. but for the domain of quantum computing.

It would be really helpful if someone could direct me toward such a platform. Thanks!

Comment: I feel it might be difficult to decide if your coding result is right compared with the classical case?

Comment: I know [qiskit](https://qiskit.org/learn) has a vast array of documentation with challenges etc. for people learning to try. It is code oriented and they have regular new challenges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Last time I checked, there was not any DAILY-basis automatic training platform for quantum SDK.

[Qiskit Learn](https://qiskit.org/learn/) list a vast array of documentation, including videos and Summer School content. The [Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/content/ch-ex/) is an interactive guide on how to use Qiskit, specially if you know already some of the algorithms but do not know how to code them in this language. Qiskit community also makes twice-per-year challenges and a summer school every year where you can train your coding skills.

[QWorld](https://qworld.net/) also organises online schools, that are evaluated on online coding challenges using Qiskit and cirq.

QWorld and Qiskit challenges use an automatic platform that automatically evaluates if your code is right.

Another thing that might need a mention are [quantum katas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/tutorial-qdk-intro-to-katas) in Microsoft Q#, which are short exercises (with solutions) that are related to important quantum routines that you should master. Some can be run directly on mybinder.org.

Finally, the [Quantum Open Source Foundation](https://qosf.org/) (QOSF) has a big list of resources you can check. They also have a mentoring program and monthly challenges if you are up for more regular training. If there is another platform that is closer to what you are looking for, it is definetely listed in [QOSF resource list](https://qosf.org/learn_quantum/).

Comment: QOSF also has a list of monthly challenges! https://github.com/qosf/monthly-challenges

Comment: @RajivKrishnakumar Thanks, I forgot to add the link.

Answer (score 1):

[The Quantum Katas](https://github.com/Microsoft/QuantumKatas/) project mentioned by Mauricio was actually inspired by TopCoder and Codeforces-style programming competitions. It offers not only programming problems on quantum computing, but also testing harnesses that check that your solution is correct, same as online judges do (though you have to run them locally or online on Binder, most of these problems are not integrated into an actual online judge).

For a purely Codeforces experience, Microsoft has hosted several programming competitions on Codeforces in 2018-2020, so there are 6 problem sets you can solve there:

- [Microsoft Q# Coding Contest — Summer 2018](https://codeforces.com/contest/1002) and [Warmup Round](https://codeforces.com/contest/1001).
- [Microsoft Q# Coding Contest — Winter 2019](https://codeforces.com/contest/1116) and [Warmup Round](https://codeforces.com/contest/1115).
- [Microsoft Q# Coding Contest — Summer 2020](https://codeforces.com/contest/1357/) and [Warmup Round](https://codeforces.com/contest/1356/).